# Best practice to create a new account with facebook login users

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

In my iOS application someone can manually create an account (providing email and password). These information are sent to my webservice that actually creates the account in my database.

But now I would like to add facebook login to my application. Thus I'm using the Facebook API to connect the user.

I can connect the user via the facebook API but I also need to create an account for him in my database (to remember his preferences in the application and other stuff). 
How can I create this account for him ? Which information from facebook should I store in my database ? I mean, I can get the user ID to store it to recognize the user next time he connects via the facebook API but it's not secure, anyone knowing this ID could connect.

So, what is the best practice to create an account for a facebook user and to create an internal session for him every time he connects via facebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a though - you can just store the facebook id of the user in your database and when someone tries to connect to your app through fb, you can retrieve the fb id of that account at that point and run it against the fb ids stored in your db right?

Even if one knows the fb id of some other person they can't actually do anything because you won't be getting the fb id manually from the user, but directly from the fb account that's connected to your app. So unless one knows the username and password of that other person too, knowing the id alone won't help them i guess. I think this would be okay

**Edit:**
I guess you can try this. Have two ids for every user in your database. One is an auto-incrementing unique id and the second one is the facebook id of that user, in case he connects his fb account to your app. Whenever some action has to be performed, do it based on the first unique id. This way, even if someone knows the fb id of another person he won't know the first unique id.

Now, when you need to do some action using the fb id, you can first verify that the user is logged in to your app through fb. If he is, you can just go ahead because now you know that the person isn't faking it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, using the id alone can be a problem because even if the user won't be able to do facebook specific actions through my app, he will be able to connect to my app as another user and to update profile information and other stuff

Comment: But how can my app know the user's id? I have to send it to him via the webservice, and if I do so, someone can catch it. However I think I will have troubles with security in any case. Actually, what I did is close to your solution which seems to be the best one we can find. I get the fb id and email of the user, I crypt these information and I use them to log in.

Comment: Oh. This will be useful for me too. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add my solution to yours

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to leave this here :

You should only sent the access_token / code to your backend. At the backend you call the graph api to retrieve the facebook UID from the access token ( That's why you store the app secret in your server ). After that, depending on your logic, you can check your database to see if the UID already exist.